# Defining partially applied typeclasses

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Exploring the idea that [typeclasses are essentially C++ abstract classes without nested inheritance](https://wiki.haskell.org/OOP_vs_type_classes#Type_classes_are_like_interfaces.2Fabstract_classes.2C_not_classes_itself), I have written the typeclass

```
class Interface i c where
    i :: c -> i

instance Interface i i where i = id

infixl 1 #
(#) :: Interface i c => c -> (i -> r) -> r
c # f = f $ i c
```

With an interface like

```
data IDrawable' = IDrawable { draw :: IO () }
```

I'd like to have something like

```
type IDrawable c = Interface IDrawable' c
```

So that I could do

```
data Object = Object { objectDraw :: IO () }
data Person = Person { personDraw :: IO () }

instance IDrawable Object where i = IDrawable . objectDraw
instance IDrawable Person where i = IDrawable . personDraw
```

While the `type IDrawable c` compiles with `ConstraintKinds`, I'm not allowed to do `instance IDrawable Object where i = IDrawable . objectDraw` with the error

```
'i' is not a (visible) method of class 'IDrawable`
```

Is there a way to declare `IDrawable c = Interface IDrawable' c` so that it can be instanced?

This is purely out of academic interest, I'm not recommending anyone use this pattern in a real application, I just want to know if this sort of thing is possible without applying `TemplateHaskell` or `CPP`.

Comment: Did you mean `(#) :: Interface c i => c -> (i -> r) -> r`?

Comment: @AndrásKovács or `class Interface i c where` instead, but it amounts to the same problem.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible (as of 7.8.3, and I think also 7.10); it's [GHC bug #7543](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7543).  It's not a very trafficked bug; there are clearly at least a few people who'd like to be able to write this sort of thing (*e.g.*, you, Edward Kmett), but mostly this goes unnoticed.  There's no progress on changing this behavior recorded on the tracker.

As for why you can't, let me paraphrase Simon Peyton-Jones's explanation on the bug tracker.  The problem is that type checking instances has two parts: first, GHC has to look up where the method names (here, `i`) are from; second, GHC has to expand the type synonyms.  Because these two steps are performed in this issue by two different components of GHC, constraint synonym instances can't be supported; GHC can't tell what class it needs to look in to find `i`.

---

The other reason this is a bug – and the reason I found this, as per the comments on [András Kovács's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29039865/237428) – is that the current behavior isn't as simple as "it doesn't work".  Instead, it *tries* to work, but you can't declare any methods… but you *can* declare a methodless instance!  In GHCi:

```
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
...
Prelude> :set -XMultiParamTypeClasses -XFlexibleInstances -XConstraintKinds
Prelude> class Interface i c where i :: c -> i
Prelude> instance Interface i i where i = id
Prelude> let (#) :: Interface i c => c -> (i -> r) -> r ; c # f = f $ i c ; infixl 1 #
Prelude> data IDrawable' = IDrawable { draw :: IO () }
Prelude> type IDrawable = Interface IDrawable'
Prelude> instance IDrawable () where i _ = IDrawable $ return ()

<interactive>:8:29:
    ‘i’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘IDrawable’
Prelude> ()#draw

<interactive>:9:3:
    No instance for (Interface IDrawable' ()) arising from a use of ‘#’
    In the expression: () # draw
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = () # draw
Prelude> instance IDrawable () where {}

<interactive>:10:10: Warning:
    No explicit implementation for
      ‘i’
    In the instance declaration for ‘Interface IDrawable' ()’
Prelude> ()#draw
*** Exception: <interactive>:10:10-21: No instance nor default method for class operation Ghci1.i
```

In other words:

```
instance IDrawable () where i _ = IDrawable $ return ()
```

fails, but

```
instance IDrawable () where {}
```

succeeds!  So clearly, the check needs to either be loosened or tightened, depending on the desired behavior :-)

---

P.S.: One more thing: You should always eta-reduce type synonyms as much as possible.  This is why I changed `IDrawable` to

```
type IDrawable = Interface IDrawable'
```

and dropped the `c` parameter on both sides in the `GHCi` code above.  The advantage of this is that since type synonyms can't be partially applied, you can't pass your version of `IDrawable` as a parameter to anything; however, the fully eta-reduced version can be passed anywhere expecting something of kind `* -> Constraint`.

(This is touched on in [András Kovács's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29039865/237428), and I mentioned this in a comment there; nevertheless, since I ended up writing an answer too, I figured I'd add it here as well.)

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer.  It's not often I come across a bug in GHC.  I've commented on trac to see if maybe we can get it resolved one way or the other.  I can see where if it were implemented just right it could make it easier to work with and compose typeclasses, so I'm interested to see what can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a "partial" class with no instances:

```
class Interface IDrawable' c => IDrawable c

instance Interface IDrawable' Object where i = IDrawable . objectDraw
instance Interface IDrawable' Person where i = IDrawable . personDraw
```

Alternatively, constraint synonyms could be used:

```
type IDrawable c = Interface IDrawable' c
```

The classy solution is probably preferable though, since the `IDrawable` class has a proper `* -> Constraint` kind, while the type synonym is unusable unless fully applied. This can be relevant, since data definitions (and type families and pretty much all type-level hackery) can only make use of proper type constructors.

Comment: You could reduce the type synonym issues by using `type IDrawable = Interface IDrawable'` (i.e., eta-reducing the definition to get rid of `c`) – you still couldn't declare an instance of `IDrawable`, but you could pass it as a type-level argument, you wouldn't need spurious instances of some new `IDrawable` class, etc.

Comment: @AntalS-Z What I was looking for is "you still couldn't declare an instance of `IDrawable`".  I doubt there's any documentation as to why, but is there a more thorough explanation as to why?

Comment: @bheklilr: Sorry, I should have been clearer that the comment was addressed at the second half of this answer only.  As for why… well, because `IDrawable` isn't a class, I suppose :-)  There's not much beyond that, I don't think.  And I'd imagine things would become weird if you had to expand out type synonyms before deciding if they were valid instance heads.  But then, `TypeSynonymInstances` allows this for arguments, so maybe it's just that nobody has done it.

Comment: @bheklilr: Actually, hang on, there's a weird bug going on here: check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/antalsz/c8a2cc435fe92f4eb276) of your desired code running in GHCi.  I can't create the instance if I define the method, but I can if I don't.  So the check about  `IDrawable` doesn't work, but I can't tell if it ought to be loosened or tightened!

Comment: @bheklilr: I found the relevant GHC bug: it's [ticket 7543](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7543), with some comments about why this doesn't work.  It sounds like the issue is that type synonym expansion and type class method name resolution are done by two different parts of the compiler, so they can't interact properly.

Comment: @AntalS-Z Well that's interesting.  Maybe I can get the discussion going again on the bug tracker.  That's a good explanation as to why I can't do what I want, thanks!