# Haskell type class alias and module re-export

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm struggling with Haskell's type classes at the moment. I'm using the language extension `{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}` to give a type class a type alias.

The module containing the type class looks something like that:

```
module Foo.Bar.Class
( C (..)
) where

class C a where
  foo :: a
```

Now I want to hide the internal definition of the type class and expose a more restricted interface of the type class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

module Foo.Bar where
( Class
) where

import qualified Foo.Bar.Class as C


type Class = C
```

The cabal file adds Foo.Bar.Class to the hidden list of modules and Foo.Bar to the exposed module list.

But when I try to use the so defined type class the compiler starts complaining that `foo` is not a (visible) function of the type class `Class`.

My instance looks like so:

```
data FooBar = Foo | Bar

instance Class (FooBar -> String) where
  foo Foo = "foo"
  foo Bar = "bar"
```

Adding `(..)` behind the export of `Class` or `C.foo` to the module export didn't help me get `foo` visible. Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see several things wrong with your code, but I'm still not sure exactly what you're trying to *achieve*. You want the class to be hidden, but you don't want the class to be hidden...?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I don't want to expose it directly. I want to wrap a little EDSL around it to make it useful. The class itself needs to be visible from outside but I don't want users of the library to be forced to import the type class qualified. The hiding of the module where the class definition relies is just for structuring of my source code internally in the project. I hope that clarifies it a bit.

PS: I'm quite new to Haskell so please excuse any mistakes I made. I didn't understand all internals of Haskell yet.

Comment: "I don't want to expose it" / "The class needs to be visible". Uh, still confused. What exactly do you want to be visible? (And what does "qualified" have to do with it?)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I want every class and type to be in it's own source file as far as I can. For me it's more logical to structure my sources this way. By exposing the module `Foo.Bar` I want the user to get access to the type class `C` defined in `Foo.Bar.Class`. My type class is named `C` in my sources too. I have multiple type classes and types which are just named `C` and `T`. For this to work I need qualified import. But re-exporting the type class under a different name does not work as I expect it to behave.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid In a third source file I want `import FooBar` only. I don't want to import all implementation details. As the compilation error started with the constraint kind (`type Class = T.C`) I think it has to do with it. I guess I did something wrong with my module export declaration in `Foo.Bar`.

Comment: You can't create aliases for *classes*, only types (and functions, obviously). A class can never be renamed. If I were you... don't name all your classes `C`! Problem solved... (Do you actually need classes to begin with?)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I will try it the other way now. But it is indeed possible with the GHC extension `{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}`. :)

Comment: When you export the `Class`, you don't export `foo` with it. In the end `Class` just refers to the class, not to `foo`. If you also want `foo` to be re-export, you need to do that explicitely. However, like MathematicalOrchid said, you probably should just give your classes/types different names.

Comment: @Kritzefitz Specifying explicitly didn't fix the problem. I'll try to get it working and maybe file a bug the GHC team. I guess it's a problem in the compiler. Explicitly exporting the function definitions in the class didn't help. For now I'll do it the "normal" way.

Comment: I could imagine that it doesn't work because `Class` doesn't actually refer to `C`, but rather to a type that fulfils the constraint `C` (thus it's actually `(C a) => a`, in which case it's by design that you can't make an instance of `Class`. I never worked with `ConstraintKinds` though, but just guessed that by the name.

Comment: I could even imagine that you're right. But wouldn't the possibility to create instances of the aliased class via the alias just a pure logical behavior?

Comment: See https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7543. There are technical reasons for GHC's behavior explained in the first comment. You should assume that the thing that comes after `instance` has to actually be the name of the class you want to write an instance for.

Comment: @ReidBarton Oh thanks for the link! So what I'm trying to accomplish isn't even possible, I guess.

Comment: I don't know that it's quite a duplicate, but see also ["Defining partially applied typeclasses"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29039526/237428) (full disclosure: which I answered), which addresses the same impossibility.